# Как спарсенное число 1,017 (пример) привести к int 1017?

Tags: python

Запятая может плавать (может быть и не запятая, а точка или другой символ). Интересует универсальное решение

Comment: Что такое спарсенное число?

Comment: я его спарсил допустим BS с web

Comment: Что значит «спарсить»?

Comment: Что значит вы его спарсили?

Comment: нашел на веб странице при помощи https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ для дальнейшего использования в коде

Comment: @dimahimma: Это не называется парсить. Веб-скрейпинг не имеет ничего общего с синтаксическим анализом.

Comment: понял, буду знать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно просто убрать запятую и привести к `int`:

```
s = '1,012'
int(s.replace(',','').replace('.','')) #1012
```

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений оставить в строке только цифры:

```
import re
s = '1-2dsd.lwjkq   q   sas343toi|'
print(int(re.sub('\D','',s)))  # 12343
```

Comment: а без регулярок? вдруг там попадется например не , а . ?

Comment: @dimahimma какие же тут регулярки. Это обычная замена символа. С помощью регулярок можно убрать все не-цифры.

Comment: блин ну все возможные варианты перечислять тоже не вариант, надо что то по питоновски лаконичное и крутое

Comment: @dimahimma что за все возможные варианты? Такие подробности должны быть указаны прямо в вопросе, отредактируйте его

Comment: отредактировал...

Comment: тьфу, пересекаемся, а т.к. я позже ответил, удалю свой ответ :)

Answer (score 4):

```
int(''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, '123qew213')))
```

Comment: так кстати быстрее будет, чем через регулярки

Answer (score 2):

Тоже самое без функции высшего порядка

```
int(''.join([x for x in '1,017' if x in "1234567890"]))
```

Для дробных:

```
float(''.join([x for x in '1,017.213' if x in ".1234567890"]))
```

Comment: Можно заменить на `if x.isdigit()`

Comment: С текстовыми методами теряется функциональность, набор допустимых символов может быть изменён для двоичных систем и др.